# Python django : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django

I am trying to launch django-app in ubuntu server using

```
/opt$ sudo python peace/src/manage.py runserver
```

I am getting error as "`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`"

I am able to launch the same app in my dev-environment eclipse IDE in windows.!!

My folder structure > /opt/peace/src/manage.py

settings folder structure > `/opt/peace/src/peace/settings/`

manage.py :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "peace.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Please advice,

Full error-log

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-246:/opt$ sudo python peace/src/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peace/src/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 23, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 24, in Migration
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

.. /settings/base.py

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()

# Ideally move env file should be outside the git repo
# i.e. BASE_DIR.parent.parent
env_file = join(dirname(__file__), 'local.env')
if exists(env_file):
    environ.Env.read_env(str(env_file))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# Raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

local.env

```
DEBUG=True
# syntax: DATABASE_URL=psql://username:password@127.0.0.1:8458/database
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///db.sqlite3
SECRET_KEY="v(jkz$=0+nj38pmf%iqddjok47zcgt+h%9*6ehn=2vbbj3%vj&"
```

Comment: What does you `settings.py` file look like? Does it contain a `SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: it needs `SECRET_KEY="SOMETHING....ANYTHING REALLY!!"`

Comment: @JoranBeasley , @ Leistungsagfall . Yes  SECRET_KEY  is set in settings file. Edited question to include settings info
Also I am able to launch the same app in my dev-environment eclipse IDE in windows.!!

Comment: Why are you running the server via `sudo`? That's a bad idea, and might even be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are not referring to the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` properly. In your manage.py, you are pointing to just `peace.settings`, but you probably need to point to one of the modules in there, for instance, `peace.settings.base`.